# MySQL Query Optimization for two tables where ID does not exits in 2nd table

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

We have this below MySQL query. while the query runs smoothly in localhost with huge data, it takes a lot of time in live server. i tried to optimize it but to no wain. can this code be written in more simpler term?
help will be really appreciated.

```
SELECT id, Request_By, Org_Name, Branch_Name, SALES_PERSON, Is_Consignee, Is_Shipper, EmailId, Telephone, Credit_LimitRS, IE_Code_No,
    PAN_No, Credit_limitDAYS, GL_Link 
    FROM mst_ship_con_newcust
    WHERE ( not EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM mst_branch_info b where b.id = mst_ship_con_newcust.id) ) 
    ORDER BY id desc
```

Comment: Pls post the result of the explain from the server, and also let us know roughly how long it takes the server to execute the query, and how many records you have in the tables.

Comment: I get the data, but it takes around 3 1/2 to 4 mins to show the result in live server

Comment: Ok. Pls show us the result of the explain. Until then it is a pure guesswork.

Comment: How? Please guide. I am showing data from first table only where the primary id of first table is not in second table yet.

Comment: `explain select ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, Request_By, Org_Name, Branch_Name, SALES_PERSON, Is_Consignee,    Is_Shipper, EmailId, Telephone, Credit_LimitRS, IE_Code_No,
PAN_No, Credit_limitDAYS, GL_Link 
FROM mst_ship_con_newcust
  LEFT JOIN mst_branch_info b ON b.id = mst_ship_con_newcust.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
ORDER BY id desc
```

What about LEFT JOIN like this?

UPDATE:

```
SELECT id, Request_By, Org_Name, Branch_Name, SALES_PERSON, Is_Consignee,    Is_Shipper, EmailId, Telephone, Credit_LimitRS, IE_Code_No,
PAN_No, Credit_limitDAYS, GL_Link 
FROM mst_ship_con_newcust
  JOIN mst_branch_info b ON b.id = mst_ship_con_newcust.id
ORDER BY id desc
```

Then just JOIN

Comment: Thanks, but i want to show where mst_ship_con_newcust.id in not exiting in b.id, yet

Comment: `LEFT` is needed to limit output to "not existing...yet".

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual to join two tables on `id`.  What is the history of this schema design?

Be sure to have indexes starting with `id` on both tables, then try

```
SELECT  y.id, y.Request_By, y.Org_Name, y.Branch_Name, y.SALES_PERSON,
        y.Is_Consignee, y.Is_Shipper, y.EmailId, y.Telephone,
        y.Credit_LimitRS, y.IE_Code_No, y.PAN_No, y.Credit_limitDAYS,
        y.GL_Link
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  n.id
            FROM  mst_ship_con_newcust AS n
            LEFT JOIN  mst_branch_info AS b  ON b.id = n.id
            WHERE  b.id IS NULL 
    ) AS x
    JOIN  mst_ship_con_newcust AS y USING (id)
    ORDER BY  id desc
```